# Django admin override FK field and expose in Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a simple Model:

```
class Tier(models.Model):
    number_groups = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Which can be a FK of another Model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    tier = models.ForeignKey(
        AccountTier,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    number_groups = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The `number_groups` attribute can be overridden in the `Account` Model. This allow my users to Select, in the admin page, from a list of predefined Tier instances. Sometimes though a user might want to set a specific value to `number_groups` that should only live in the Account instances.

I was thinking a straight way to do this was with a method in the `Account` Model:

```
def number_groups(self):
    if self.number_groups:
        return self.number_groups
    elif self.tier:
        return self.tier.number_groups
    return self.number_groups
```

But with this approach I can't make this field appear in the Admin, which is defined:

```
@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('number_groups',)
```

What is the best way to have the admin correctly show this field and allow overriding it in the `Account` Instance ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add a custom field to `admin.ModelAdmin`:

```
@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('get_number_groups', )
    readonly_fields = ('get_number_groups', )

    def get_number_groups(self, obj):
        return obj.number_groups()

    # Optional:
    # get_number_groups.short_description = 'foobar'
```